# Get object from list using reflection

Tags: java, testing, reflection, comparison, automated-tests

I am writing some webdriver tests, that go and validate web pages. Pages contain mostly web tables. I am storing my test data in objects so I am passing expected object to the test and compare it with the actual object in the web page. Test data objects are very simple and mostly just contain a bunch of strings :

```
public class PetOwnerDTO {
    private String ownerPhoneNr;
    private String ownerEmail;
    private String ownerAddress;
    // getters and setters skipped
}
```

Now since there are a lot of different objects that need to be validated, I am trying to develop a generic object comparer that would do that for me. What I have already:

```
package Helpers;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.fail;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalToIgnoringCase;

public class ObjectComparer {

    public static void compareObjects(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        assertThat(obj1, is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(obj2, is(notNullValue()));
        Class obj1Class = obj1.getClass();
        Class obj2Class = obj2.getClass();
        assertThat(obj1Class, is(sameInstance(obj2Class)));
        if (obj1Class.isArray()) {
            assertThat("Object2 is not an array", (obj2Class.isArray()));
            assertThat(Array.getLength(obj1), is(equalTo(Array.getLength(obj2))));
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(obj1); i++) {
                Object value1 = Array.get(obj1, i);
                Object value2 = Array.get(obj2, i);
                compareObjects(value1, value2);
            }
        }
        if (obj1 instanceof List<?>){
            throw new RuntimeException("Lists not supported, use looping");
        }
        Field[] fieldsObj1 = obj1Class.getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] fieldsObj2 = obj2Class.getDeclaredFields();
        assertThat(fieldsObj1.length, is(equalTo(fieldsObj2.length)));
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldsObj1.length; i++) {
            fieldsObj1[i].setAccessible(true);
            fieldsObj2[i].setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Object valueObj1 = fieldsObj1[i].get(obj1);
                Object valueObj2 = fieldsObj2[i].get(obj2);
                assertThat(valueObj1.toString(), is(equalToIgnoringCase(valueObj2.toString())));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                fail("Unable to compare objects");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with the second if:

```
if (obj1 instanceof List<?>){
```

How can I get the objects from the list? Something similar to `Array.get()`?
Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to avoid implementing `equals()` in each test object. That strikes me as a bad idea. There are many ways to speed up the implementation of an `equals()` method, including:

- Letting your IDE generate it. Eclipse, for sure, supports this idea.
- Relying on a third party library, such as Apache Commons Lang [`EqualsBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html), which could look as simple as:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
  }
  ```

I would strongly suggest you adopt ones of these approaches, rather than constructing a cunning reflection-based class that tests equality on a field-by-field basis. There are many benefits from having a proper equality method, including:

- Correct behaviour of these items when placed into a set.
- Ability to call normal JUnit assertions (`assertEquals()` etc.)

Don't forget to write a `hashCode()` method when you change `equals()`. Again, there are shortcuts for that (including [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html)).

Comment: That is cool, but the problem is, that at the moment, when using ie Assert.assertTrue(obj1.equals(obj2); i only receive an AssertionError (or i could probably somehow log it), whereas my own way with using assertThat gives me : "Expected :abc Actual :dsg". Even if using assertThat with that equals, the best i could get is Expected :true got :false

Comment: @ErkiM. I've written a `DifferenceBuilder` that [I've submitted to Apache Commons Lang](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-637), which will probably do exactly what you want. I hope this will be released in February sometime.

Comment: @ErkiM. Since writing that last comment, I've become an Apache Commons committer and my first act was to add that code to trunk. A new release will be cut in the next week or so. Keep an eye on the commons website or follow [@ApacheCommons](https://twitter.com/ApacheCommons) for announcements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try toArray()-Methods of the List-API. Please note, that you have to have the same number of the list items to compare it properly.